# The method of " queryintentactivities " it didn't work in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, android-launcher, android-query

The problem background:
above code is working fine on previous versions of Android.
I want to query the app which already installed in device.

My code:

```
public static List<String> getHomes() {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : resolveInfo) {
        names.add(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
    }
    return names;
}
```

And the above code is working fine on previous versions of Android.

Questions:
But it didn't work in Lollipop

So, is anybody has to solve this problem? or is there any other method can replace it?

Thank You~